# Display ReactJS Components Within a Scrollable List with height:auto

Tags: reactjs

How can I render the same component inside a map, without overlapping, but one below another

Here's what i mean:

```
return (
    <div className='app'>
        {[0, 1, 2, 3].map(element => {
            return(<MyComponent props = {element}/>)
        })}
    </div>
)
```

How can I display that component in a scrollable list, considering that its height is auto?

Comment: What you're asking for is the default behavior of html (assuming MyComponent is wrapped in a div). Each div stacked one below the other vertically. What is happening that you don't expect? Your map looks fine other than the props, it should be`<MyComponent propName={value}/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You are Describing the Default Behavior Already

> How can I display that component in a scrollable list, considering that *its height is auto?* [emphasis mine]

With `height:auto;`, the behavior you describe happens already:

```css
.item {
  height:300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='app'>
    <div id="1" class="item"></div>
    <div id="2" class="item"></div>
    <div id="3" class="item"></div>
</div>
```

#### But if you wanted a Limited Scroll

You need two things:

1. You need to add [**`overflow-y`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) to be set to `scroll`.
2. You need to set the height to how much of a scrollbar you want.

```css
.app {
  height: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  height:30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='app'>
    <div id="1" class="item"></div>
    <div id="2" class="item"></div>
    <div id="3" class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following css:

```
.app{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     gap: 2vh;
     overflow-y: auto;
}
```